# How To Update a Row With Multiple Combined Rows In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have two tables as decribe bellow:

`Table1`

```
id | table2_id | value
1  | 1         | AAA
2  | 1         | BBB
3  | 1         | CCC
```

`Table2`

```
id | value
1  | XXXX
```

and I want to update `Table2` with combined value from `Table1`.

OUTPUT Expected on `Table2`

```
id | value
1  | AAA,BBB,CCC
```

How can I do or there are the best way to get expected result that explained above just using TSQL in sql server?

Comment: you could iterate a cursor to get the combined value, then fire update query on table2.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Storing comma delimited values is not really a good design.

Comment: Maybe that out of topic wit can be discussed on another thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `Common Table Expression` on this,

```
WITH record
AS
(
    SELECT [table2_id],
            STUFF((SELECT ',' + [value]
                    FROM Table1
                    WHERE [table2_id] = a.[table2_id]
                    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')  AS val_list
    FROM    Table1 AS a
    GROUP   BY [table2_id]
)
UPDATE  a
SET     a.value = b.val_list
FROM    table2 a
        INNER JOIN record b
            ON a.ID = b.table2_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bf3b/7)

Answer (score 0):

After exploring [JW 웃](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491243/jw) answer, I have modify and do simplest way as query bellow:

```
UPDATE table2
SET table2.value = STUFF((SELECT ',' + [value]
                        FROM Table1
                        WHERE [table2_id] = a.[table2_id]
                        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM Table1 a 
WHERE table2.ID = a.table2_id
```

Here at [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bf3b/13)